# how to get all the csv file name under a directory?

Tags: php

supposed there is a folder named `example`, and in it there are some csv file eg`(a.csv, b.csv....`).

the `test.php` directory is the same as `example` folder.  now i want to pass all the csv file name to the following if condition. namely, replace `test.csv` with all the csv file name

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r"))
```

how do i do?

i using the following code:

```
$files=  glob("./example/*.csv");
 if (($handle = fopen("$files", "r"))
```

but it doesn't work. thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`$files` is an array, you need to loop with it.

```
$files = glob("./example/*.csv");
foreach($files as $filepath) {
  if ($handle = fopen($filepath, "r")) {
     // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: the value is like [0] => ./example/Canvas.csv. i only want to Canvas.csv. how to change  glob("./example/*.csv"); thank you.

Comment: @down If you know the filename you want, you don't need glob, or `files[0]` will give you the first element value.

Comment: i mean when i print_r($files). it's output is like [0] => ./example/Canvas.csv.  i only want to the last part to be passed to $filepath

Comment: @down You should see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php, `$files[0]` gives what you want.